# Pivotting SQL Table Response to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, formatting, ecmascript-6

## Issue

Our API returns two formats JSON and this SQL table format. I'm not sure what it is truly called so I'll give a few examples below. Like all API responses, it can be a list or a single response but it is always in the same format. I'm creating a utility function for this SQL table format to be converted into a JSON object so the front-end only needs to be concerned with a single format, JSON.

## Problem

Convert SQL Table Response to JSON

## Examples of the SQL table format

Here is the SQL table format as a success message.

```
{
  "COLUMNS":["SUCCESS","RETMESSAGE"],
  "DATA":[[true,"Order Approved"]]
}
```

Here is an example of a list

```
{
  "COLUMNS":["PRODUCTID","PRODUCTNAME"],
  "DATA":[[1001,"Product1"],[1002,"Product2"],[1003,"Product3"]]
}
```

## Current Solution

The current solution is the following. It works well but I keep coming back to it and thinking there is a more elegant way of writing this.

```js
const request = {
        "COLUMNS":["SUCCESS","RETMESSAGE"],
        "DATA":[[true,"Order Approved"]]
      };

const desiredFormat = [{
        "SUCCESS":true,
        "RETMESSAGE":"Order Approved"
      }];

function tableToJSON (dataset) {
    const data = dataset.DATA;
    const columns = dataset.COLUMNS;
    const jsonData = [];
    data.forEach( (row) => {
      const json = {};
      row.forEach( (item, index) => {
        json[columns[index]] = item;
      });
      jsonData.push(json);
    });
    return jsonData;
  }

const formattedResponse = tableToJSON(request);

console.log(JSON.stringify(formattedResponse) === JSON.stringify(desiredFormat))
// Outputs: True
```

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Ah you want to _pivot_ data. Now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have code that sets up an array, then has a loop to push items into that array, [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) could be used to condense that code. For example, these lines:

> ```
> const jsonData = [];
> data.forEach( (row) => {
>   const json = {};
>   row.forEach( (item, index) => {
>     json[columns[index]] = item;
>   });
>   jsonData.push(json);
> });
> return jsonData;
> ```

Could be simplified to this:

```
return data.map( (row) => {
  const json = {};
  row.forEach( (item, index) => {
    json[columns[index]] = item;
  });
  return json;
});
```

You could optionally simplify the inner loop using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
return data.map( (row) => {
  return row.reduce( (json, item, index) => {
    json[columns[index]] = item;
    return json;
  }, {});
});
```

There are some good exercises in [*Functional Programming in Javascript*](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) where you practice implementing some of those methods.